# Dynamic sequence of promise (Q) never go to catch

Tags: javascript, promise, q

I have a number of promises (using Q) that i want to call sequentially, here's my code :

```
// All the promises are called sequentially
            var result = promises.reduce(function(promise, item) {
                return promise.then(function () {
                    var obj = toPush.shift();
                });
            }, Q());

            // Check the result
            result.then(function() {
                // Do something if all of the promises full
            }).catch(function() {
                // Do something if ONE of the promise is rejected and stop the others
            }).finally(function() {
                App.network.stopLoader();
            });
```

promises is an array of promise (callback functions)

It works greats, all the promises are done sequentially, but when a promise is rejected, it still go in the then function instead of the catch. 
Why ?

I have used this : [Break a dynamic sequence of promises with Q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24261379/break-a-dynamic-sequence-of-promises-with-q)

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: What is `promises`, what is `toPush`? Why are you shifting from it, and what are you doing with `obj`? It doesn't look as if your sequential code was asynchronous at all.

Comment: promises is a tab which contain an array of functions which return promises, toPush is a tab that allow me to construct the tab promises, if a promise is resolved, then toPush.shift, else i need to stop all the others promises and save toPush.

Comment: Those functions in the `promises` array are never really called - you don't use `item`! I wonder why you think they are executed fine.

Comment: I changed that, still doesn't work.

Comment: Changed how? Please [edit] your question to amend it with the new code

Comment: @HuguesOdegaard, it's hard to understand what you are trying to achieve. A promise represents the outcome of an asynchronous process. As such, promises cannot be "called" and an array of promises is not a sequence. In order to form a sequence, you would typically reduce an array of data or an array of functions to form a sequence. To end up somewhere meaningful, you must start out in the right place.

Answer (score 0):

The reason the catch is never called is because ou don't return anything in this part of the code:

```
return promise.then(function () {
    var obj = toPush.shift();
});
```

Instead you should try:

```
return promise.then(function () {
    return toPush.shift();
});
```

If you do:

```
result.then(console.log)
```

you should always see **undefined** which won't be caught.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it doesn't work. But I should probably return something, you're right.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just want Q.all:

```
Q.all(promises).then(function() {
  // Do something if all of the promises full
}).catch(function() {
  // Do something if ONE of the promise is rejected and stop the others
}).finally(function() {
  App.network.stopLoader();
});
```

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/kriskowal/q#combination), the promise returned by all will be rejected as soon as any of the promises in the array is rejected. (As opposed to allSettled that waits for all the promises to resolve before resolving the returned promise).